# Implementing small functions in a header file, including in two different files in the same project

Tags: c++, linker, header-files, one-definition-rule

A quote from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/) about whether to ever implement functions in header files:

> 1. For classes used in only one file that aren’t generally reusable, define them directly in the single .cpp file they’re used in.
> 2. For classes used in multiple files, or intended for general reuse, define them in a .h file that has the same name as the class.
> 3. Trivial member functions (trivial constructors or destructors, access functions, etc…) can be defined inside the class.
> 4. Non-trivial member functions should be defined in a .cpp file that has the same name as the class.

Suppose I follow the advice of #3, and I implement some small method `my_class::f` in the `my_class.h` file, but I leave the bigger methods to be implemented in `my_class.cpp`. If I include `my_class.h` in two different `.cpp` files in the same project, then the linker will see two (identical) definitions of `my_class::f`. (This is not solved by header guards.) I understand that some linkers are smart enough to tolerate this (though I've heard it can cost extra time). My question is:

> Do you think they recommend #3 because it is uncommon to include the same .h file twice across a project, or because the linker can be relied upon to ignore the duplicate definition, and will not waste too much time doing so?

Comment: You need to make the functions [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) to avoid redefinitions.

Comment: Recommend using either `.hpp` or `.hxx` for C++ header files.  This will distinguish C language header files, `.h`, from C++ header files.  The C compiler can't compile C++ header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that some linkers are smart enough to tolerate this

*All* standard conforming linkers tolerate multiple identical definitions of inline functions.

> linker can be relied upon to ignore the duplicate definition

Yes.

> and will not waste too much time doing so?

I would not expect the time wasted by the linker to be significant.

However, inline functions generally have to be compiled for each translation unit where they are used. If it is a particularly complex function, then the compiler (not linker) may end up wasting a significant amount of time. This is part of why the tutorial suggests defining only trivial functions inline.

Another reason to follow the (implied) advice (of *not* defining non-trivial functions inline) is that non-trivial functions attract changes, and modifications to header files propagate as changes to files that include those headers. Non-inline functions can cut re-compilation time to a tiny fraction of the full compilation time by virtue of not needing to be repeatedly compiled, and also not causing other translation units to be compiled when changed.

Comment: It's odd that tutorials would suggest defining most code in source files. The standard library has over a million lines of templated header-only code. And compilers might profit from having function definitions available even at 50 lines of code and still partially inline them.

Comment: @JanSchultke When you write templates, you rarely have the opportunity of defining the functions in a separate translation unit. With non-template functions though, non-inline functions can be wroth it by cutting re-compilation time to a tiny fraction of the full compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

In the recommendation #3 there is written

> Trivial member functions (trivial constructors or destructors, access
> functions, etc…) **can be defined inside the class**.

Member functions defined in a class are inline functions. So there is no problem with including the header in several compilation units.